# Can someone tell me why the button's are blank on my calculator app?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I am trying to create a GUI calculator in Python for a class assignment.

But I've run into a problem; the code below is not printing the buttons in the GUI! To see what I'm talking about, please look at the code below the commented line:

#CODE THAT IS NOT PRINTING THE BUTTON IS BELOW

It's basically buttons all of the buttons who only show what is on it once they are clicked.

Could someone assist and help me understand why this is not working? I've tried to use pack statements but they don't work either.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
    
    
    
    window = Tk()
    
    window.title("Kristo's Calculator")
    
    
    class GUI():
    
        def __init__(self, input_text, memory_text, operation):
            self.gui_input_text = input_text
            self.gui_memory_text = memory_text
            self.gui_operation = operation
    
    
            memory_display = Entry(window, textvariable=self.gui_memory_text, font=('arial', 18, 'bold')).grid(row=0,
                                                                                                               column=0,
                                                                                                               columnspan=4)
            display = Entry(window, font=('arial', 18, 'bold'), textvariable=self.gui_input_text).grid(row=1, column=0,
                                                                                                       columnspan=4)
            buttons = ['M+', 'M-', 'MR', 'MC',
                       'CA', 'Sqr', 'Del', '/',
                       '7', '8', '9', '*',
                       '4', '5', '6', '-',
                       '1', '2', '3', '+',
                       '0', '%', '.', '=','HS'
                       ]
            count = 0
            for row in range(2, 8):
                for column in range(4):
                    button = Button(window, width=10, fg="green", height=3, bd=0, bg='#fff',
                                    cursor='hand2', activebackground='#1e90ff', text=buttons[count],
                                    command=lambda i=buttons[count]: self.functions(i)).grid(row=row, column=column)
                    count += 1
    
        def functions(self, i):
            run_class = Calculations(self.gui_input_text, self.gui_memory_text, self.gui_operation)
            self.debug(fn="functions start")
    
            if (i == 'M+'):
                answer = run_class.btn_memory_add(self.gui_operation)
                self.gui_operation = answer
            elif (i == 'M-'):
                answer = run_class.btn_memory_sub(self.gui_operation)
                self.gui_operation = answer
            elif (i == 'MR'):
                answer = run_class.memory_call(self.gui_operation)
                self.gui_operation = answer
            elif (i == 'MC'):
                answer = run_class.memory_clear(self.gui_operation)
            elif (i == 'CA'):
                answer = run_class.btn_clear(self.gui_operation)
                self.gui_operation = ""
            elif (i == 'Del'):
                answer = run_class.btn_del(self.gui_operation)
                self.gui_operation = answer
            elif (i == '='):
                answer = run_class.btn_equal(self.gui_operation)
            elif (i == 'Sqr'):
                answer = run_class.btn_Sqr(self.gui_operation)
            elif (i == '%'):
                answer = run_class.percentage(self.gui_operation)
            else:
                self.gui_operation += i
                answer = run_class.btn_eval(i)
    
            self.gui_input_text.set(answer)
            self.debug(fn="functions end")
    
        def debug(self, fn=None):
            print(
                f"*** {fn} ***\nG Memory:\t{self.gui_memory_text.get()}\nG Input:\t{self.gui_input_text.get()}\nG Operation:\t{self.gui_operation}\n")
    
    
    
    class Calculations():
    
        def __init__(self, input_text, memory_text, operation):
            self.calc_input_text = input_text
            self.calc_memory_text = memory_text
            self.calc_operation = operation
            self.debug(fn="__init__")
    
        def btn_eval(self, i):
            self.debug(fn="btn_eval")
            self.calc_operation += i
            self.calc_input_text.set(self.calc_operation)
            if (len(self.calc_operation)) > 24:
                messagebox.showerror("Error Window", "Inputs too Long")
            else:
                return self.calc_operation
    
        def btn_memory_add(self, calc_operation):
            self.debug(fn="btn_memory_add")
            if self.calc_operation != '':
                Mem_ADD = self.calc_memory_text.get()
                ans = eval(Mem_ADD + "+" + self.calc_operation)
                self.calc_memory_text.set(ans)
            return ""
    
    
        def btn_memory_sub(self, i):
            self.debug(fn="btn_memory_sub")
            if self.calc_operation != '':
                Mem_Sub = self.calc_memory_text.get()
                ans = eval(Mem_Sub + '-' + self.calc_operation)
                self.calc_memory_text.set(ans)
            return ""
    
    
        def memory_call(self, calc_operation):
            self.debug(fn="memory_call")
            memory = self.calc_memory_text.get()
            input_text.set(memory)
            self.calc_memory_text.set("")
            return memory
    
    
        def memory_clear(self, calc_operation):
            self.debug(fn="memory_clear")
            self.calc_memory_text.set("")  # double check this.
            return self.calc_input_text.get()
    
    
        def btn_del(self, calc_operation):
            self.debug(fn="btn_del")
            self.calc_operation = self.calc_operation[
                                  0:len(self.calc_operation) - 1]
            return self.calc_operation
    
    
        def btn_clear(self, calc_operation):
            self.debug(fn="btn_clear")
            self.calc_operation = ""
            return ""
    
        def btn_Sqr(self, calc_operation):
            self.debug(fn="btn_Sqr")
            pass
    
        def percentage(self, calc_operation):
            self.debug(fn="percentage")
            pass
    
    
        def btn_equal(self, calc_operation):
            self.debug(fn="btn_equal")
    
            try:
                result = str(eval(self.calc_operation))
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                result = "Zero Division Error"
                self.calc_input_text.set(result)
                result = ""
            except SyntaxError:
                result = "Input Error"
                self.calc_input_text.set(result)
                result = ""
    
            if (len(result) > 10):
                result = "{:e}".format(
                    float(result))
            elif (len(result)) > 24:
                messagebox.showerror("Error Window",
                                     "answers too Long. Press Clear")
    
            self.calc_operation = result
            return result
    
        def debug(self, fn=None):
            print(
                f"*** {fn} ***\nC Memory:\t{self.calc_memory_text.get()}\nC Input:\t{self.calc_input_text.get()}\nC Operation:\t{self.calc_operation}\n")
    
    
    operation = ""
    
    input_text = StringVar()
    memory_text = StringVar()
    calculator = GUI(input_text, memory_text, operation)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not printing the buttons in the GUI"? I ran the code on my PC and the calculator is showing up and seems to work. What do you expect it to do? Where are you encountering an issue? Don't just drop code and make us go through it, you should ideally make it easy for those who try to help you, not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry, This is my first post on here. For some reason, when I run the GUI, a window appears with my calculator and all of the buttons. The only problem is, is that the buttons are all blank. I'm not sure how to fix this. I am also using a Mac so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but is there anyway you can send me a screenshot of what you see on your screen? it will help a lot.

Comment: Sure https://i.imgur.com/ZsR1L7W.png

Comment: The buttons can be shown in my Windows 10 running Python 3.8.6 as well.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on my Mac. Also, your screenshot seems to show buttons with labels on them, so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: make sure not to do this again https://www.reddit.com/r/csMajors/comments/kfexxz/can_you_guys_please_upvote_my_post_on_stack/